# YUI.Test assertion doesn't fail when it is in event's callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, yui, assertions

**I'm using version 3.4.0**

I have a strange problem with YUI.Test assertion. Here is the example:

```
YUI().use('test', 'node', 'node-event-simulate',
    function(Y) {
        var runner = Y.Test.Runner;

        var someTestCase = new Y.Test.Case({
            name    : 'SomeMeaningfulName',

            setUp       : function() {
                var test = this;

                // create show details link
                test.Y$aLink    = Y.Node
                                    .create('<a href="//some.fake.url.ie">Show details</a>');

                Y.one('body')
                    .append(test.Y$aLink);                        
            }, 

            tearDown    : function() {
                this.Y$aLink.remove();
            },

            testEventListener : function() {
                var test = this;

                test.Y$aLink
                    .on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        // this codes works
                        console.log('on click event');

                        // this one doesn't fail
                        // it "works" perfectly when it's outside of the callback
                        Y.assert(false, 'false is true');
                    });

                test.Y$aLink.simulate('click');
            }
        });

        runner.add(someTestCase);
        runner.run();
    });
```

The assertion never fails when it's inside of the event's callback :( 
Documentation doesn't mention this situation...

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but there is a lack of documentation makes it hard to be sure...

**UPDATE**

example without wait/resume:
http://jsfiddle.net/op1ekun/Fgra6/2/

and the one with wait/resume
http://jsfiddle.net/op1ekun/Fgra6/5/

**UPDATE2**

there is a similar case already reported, it touches asynchronous testing issue, but it's not my problem exactly:
http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuitest/ticket/74

**UPDATE3**

this seems to be exactly what I'm experiencing and looks a solution already proposed by Billy, the interesting thing is to use dependency injection, it might be worth a try:
http://csausdev.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/unit-testing-callbacks-with-yui-test/

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could work around the issue by setting a value in the callback, and testing it in the normal flow, but the timing might not work... hmmmm...

Answer (score 1):

YUI Test has a wait and resume mechanism you can leverage in this case. You tell it to wait until a `resume` method is called, and the `resume` method takes a callback where you can safely make assertions. In your case it would look like this:

```
'test event listener': function () {
  var test = this;

  test.Y$aLink.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    test.resume(function () {
      Assert.fail('ouch!');
    });
  });

  test.wait();
  test.Y$aLink.simulate('click');
}
```

Comment: As I assumed if I place wait() before simulate('click') method the link is never clicked :(

...but it doesn't matter, because even when I put wait() at the very end of the test I always get: "Timeout: wait() called but resume() never called."

Comment: Any news? I couldn't find a solution by myself so I switched to Jasmine (and I'm very happy), but I'm still curious what's going on. Please have a look a the updates.